# calculate contribution for each category

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset.

```
  Sales Channel         Year_Month  Total Cost
   Offline              Jul-2017    100
    Online              Jul-2017    200
    Offline              Aug-2017    300
    Online              Aug-2017    400
    Online              Sep-2017    200
    Online              Oct-2017    300
    Online              Nov-2017    100
    Offline              Nov-2017    3200
    Online              Dec-2017    500
```

I want to find percentage contribution of each category according to year_month.
Example for year_month Jul-2017
Offline percentage would be 100/(100 + 200)
Online percentage would be 200(100 + 200)

So the output should be like:

```
Sales Channel           Year_Month    Total Cost  Percentage
    Offline              Jul-2017    100          33.33%
    Online              Jul-2017    200           66.67%
    Offline              Aug-2017    300           60%
    Online              Aug-2017    200            40%
    Online              Sep-2017    200           100%
    Online              Oct-2017    300           100%
    Online              Nov-2017    100           20%
    Offline              Nov-2017    400           80%
    Online              Dec-2017    500           100%
```

I have tried iterating over year_month and then calculating for each category. But, it didn't work out.

Is there any way I can do this. If it can be done without for loop, it would be great

Answer (score 3):

If there are unique `Sales Channel` per `Year_Month` divide by `Series` created by  [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and `sum`:

```
s = df.groupby('Year_Month')['Total Cost'].transform('sum')
df['Percentage'] = df['Total Cost'].div(s).mul(100)
print (df)
  Sales Channel Year_Month  Total Cost  Percentage
0       Offline   Jul-2017         100   33.333333
1        Online   Jul-2017         200   66.666667
2       Offline   Aug-2017         300   42.857143
3        Online   Aug-2017         400   57.142857
4        Online   Sep-2017         200  100.000000
5        Online   Oct-2017         300  100.000000
6        Online   Nov-2017         100    3.030303
7       Offline   Nov-2017        3200   96.969697
8        Online   Dec-2017         500  100.000000
```

Another solution, slowier if large DataFrame and large number of groups:

```
df['Percentage'] = df.groupby('Year_Month')['Total Cost'].apply(lambda x: x / x.sum()) * 100
```